# Mule Agent REST service is not available

Tags: java, mulesoft, anypoint-studio

When I tried to setup a HTTP listener, I got this error:

[image]

[image]

Full log:

https://justpaste.it/1kvxi

This is my java_home:
[image]

[image]

I tried to change port to 808x, but it still shows the same error.

Comment: What's the exact version of Anypoint Studio? Also share the Run Configuration used.

Comment: the version of anypoint studio is 7.12.0. Where can i find run configuration? I did not change anything apart from the settings above

Comment: Run configurations are the configurations used to execute a project in Studio. Right-click your project in Package Explorer, Click Run As > Run Configurations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not a problem of the application itself but something is not working when Studio is trying to execute Mule. Maybe the workspace is corrupted. Try creating a new workspace for your application.